# Create function to merge given number of dataframes, on a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, args

I would like to create a function that takes on an undetermined number of dataframes, and then merges them on a given column, which is actually the outmost left column.

Should I use something like *args?

```
import pandas as pd

def merge_given_dfs(*args):

    pd.merge(*args,left_on='name')

merge_given_dfs(df1,df2,df3,df4)
```

Thank you!

Comment: `merge` only merges two dataframes at a time. You need either write a for loop or check out `functools.reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

try passing a list of dataframes along with other args of interests. Before any merging you can point out a df from which merging should start taking place:

```
import pandas as pd

def merge_given_dfs(initdf, dataframes, *args):
    for dataframe in dataframes:
        if initdf != dataframe:
            initdf.merge(dataframe, *args)
    return initdf
```